# Property 'showUserDropdown' does not exist on type '{}'.ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to create a basic vue component, but i get the error from the ide on the {{ showUserDropdown }} stating:

Property 'showUserDropdown' does not exist on type '{}'.ts

But i have added it to data

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ showUserDropdown }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TheCompanySiteDetailPage",
  expose: [],

  data() {
    return {
      showUserDropdown: false,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

I have googled the error and lots of suggestions say to use the definecompoennt which i have done but i still get the error

Comment: are you using volar or vetur in your vscode ?

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to fix this inconsistency:

1. Explicitly type your data using Typed. Create a file named TheCompanySiteDetailPage.vue.ts with the following contents

   ```
   import { defineComponent } from "vue";

   type TheCompanySiteDetailPageData = {
     showUserDropdown: boolean;
   };

   export default defineComponent<TheCompanySiteDetailPageData>({
     name: "TheCompanySiteDetailPage",
     expose: [],

     data() {
       return {
         showUserDropdown: false,
       };
     },
   });
   ```
2. Cast the data type in the template:

   ```
    <template>
      <div>
        {{ (data as TheCompanySiteDetailPageData).showUserDropdown }}
      </div>
    </template>
   ```